# How did this user accept his own answer less than 48 hours after his question was posted?

Tags: bug, status-completed, accepted-answer, self-answer

How did [this user](https://serverfault.com/questions/127062/issues-configuring-cups-print-server-for-ubuntu-server-9-10) accept his own answer less than 48 hours after his question was posted?

Related:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11787/accept-own-answer-immediately

Comment: Same thing happened here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533794/given-the-following-js-jquery-how-to-prevent-it-from-being-case-sensative. Also... *edit* scratch that last part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, new bug -- I just fixed it. Sorry about that (I was checking the ownership state of the question instead of the answer, got my q and a variables backwards).

Comment: Ah, you were too focused on your p's and q's, and not focused enough on your q's and a's.

Comment: That's OK as long as you make sure to cross your **`Ɨ`** 's and dot your **`Ṫ`** 's.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this certainly cannot be marked at `[status-norepo]`, as it obviously can be reproduced, and it has been!