# Question seems asked by other user

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions, users

Am I the only one seeing this, or have I completely lost it already?

http://img651.imageshack.us/img651/4150/didkoperaskthis.png

[http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/7298/appearentlyhedidnt.png](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44369/how-did-this-user-accept-his-own-answer-less-than-48-hours-after-his-question-was)

[http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/8272/sockpuppet.png](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/26428/dennis-williamson)

[The timeline shows no sign of Koper](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/44369/timeline).

Comment: You're only just under 3k away from seeing all deleted posts.

Comment: Your avatar is irritating, @voy. All this *red*. Red is the colour of fury. Change it to calming blue.

Comment: @Lad, I'm `status-bydesign`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shows who last had activity in the thread. If someone edits a post or adds a new answer, they will be shown.

In this case, Kop deleted his answer after he posted it. This means that technically he was the last person to have activity in the thread, but you can't see the activity.

10k users can [still see deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/365/why-should-10k-rep-users-view-self-deleted-answers). But [sometimes they'd rather not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23535/feature-request-ability-to-not-load-the-deleted-answers-after-hitting-10k).

Comment: This seems to be the most plausible reason.

Comment: This is correct

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- what displays in that field depends on what tab you are on (it's either owner of post, or owner of last activity on post)
- as Chacha noted, users who add then delete answers are still the owners of the last activity on the post even if you can't see it

Answer (score 0):

Last modified by.

Click on "1h ago" to jump to the latest changed post, whether it's the question or an answer.

Comment: It's not a link, just like when a question has no edits/answers.